What would have happened if the 2nd L.C.G. bag was torn during the Apollo 13 mission?
In the Apollo 13 movie, when the astronauts build the filter in order to connect the CSM and LM canisters, one of the components needed for that is an L.C.G. bag. One astronaut accidentally rips it. Luckily they have another bag onboard. I wonder what would happen if the other bag was torn too. Could there have been another way to build the filter? Could the astronauts have tried something else to escape the toxic CO2 levels (other than putting on spacesuits)?
Fred Haise figured that the CO2 would be harmless for two people in the LM. If the astronauts really couldn't do anything more, would one of them (need/want to) sacrifice himself so that the other two make it to Earth? And of course, I also wonder if things really went as depicted in the movie, concerning the filtering of the carbon dioxide.

What's now the matter? Why the downvotes? Didn't it happen like in the movie? I dunno.

Not a downvoter, but it's asking for speculation.

@OrganicMarble Not really. One can deduce from the equipment onboard whether the filter could have been built differently. Any emergency scenarios aren't necessarily that kind of speculation that's prohibited here. And if it is, one should vote to close rather than downvote.

TL;DR - it would likely not have been a problem. They had plenty of bags, and also any rips could have likely been fixed.
Fred Haise has said in interviews that while in general the movie was accurate, many of the details were dramatized, and this appears to be one of them. Reading through the audio transcript of the communications that occurred  while the astronauts assembled the filters, there does not seem to be any indication of an LCG bag being ripped.
The movie producers presumably got the dramatization idea from a mention in the written instructions for the procedure which said:

NOTE: Be careful not to rip the bag because there are only three bags onboard.

However it does not appear that this warning was included in the paraphrased instructions that were verbally read to the astronauts by Capcom Joe Kerwin.
Reading the transcripts it appears that each LCG bag had an inner and outer bag, connected at some point by a heat seal. The procedure given to them was to cut the two apart at the heat seal. The inner bags from two of the LCGs would be used for the ad hoc filters. The liquid cooling garments would then be placed back into the outer bags for storage. When the procedure was called up it was mentioned,

So take one of the LCGs and cut off the outer bag, by cutting along one the heat seals. Do it carefully and close to the heat seal, because we may have to use the outer bag if we damage the inner bag.

This indicates that there were actually six bags available to construct the two filters, three inner and three outer bags. Only two bags in total were needed.
Even if five of the bags were torn, they could have presumably reused the one remaining bag on the second filter, although this would not have allowed them to construct both filters at the same time like they did.
And even if all six bags were torn, it is not clear that it would have been a major issue. The bags already had holes cut into them by the astronauts where the suit hoses were inserted, the connection was then sealed with duct tape. If all of the bags got ripped it would likely be possible to make a repair with duct tape. In fact in the movie version Fred Haise asked this exact question after tearing the bag, although his question was not answered. The frustrated reaction of the engineer upon hearing this, and the statement that he made to Capcom Joe Kerwin, "Well they should have one bag left" was clearly meant to imply that the tear could not be fixed. However that seems to be pure conjecture on the part of the script writers.
However even though unlikely to be a fatal mistake, the mission planners obviously wanted to avoid this, thus the mention in the instructions to avoid tearing the bags.
